# Executing a talend job using API

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, talend

Is it possible to execute/run a talend job using API ?
I have a user in Salesforce who will provide a date field and click a button. Once the button is clicked, I want to send the date inserted in the field to a talend job for execution using HTTP Request.

I looked at different components in Talend and couldn't find one. I only found the tREST component that can be used to get or post data. The get could work but that assumes that the job is already running. I want a kind of a trigger to launch the execution of the job.

Comment: If the job has been published to TMC, yes, there are API’s for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Talend subscription, and your job is in the TAC, then it can be called using an API.
If you are using Talend Open Studio, then you need to set up your own server (using php for example, or any other language), and have php execute your Talend job launcher when you call the url.